# Temporary mutability of a member variable

Tags: c++, mutable

Is it possible to have a member variable only be considered mutable for a given function/code block?

e.g.

```
class Foo() {
  int blah;
  void bar() const {
    blah = 5; // compiler error
  }
  void mutable_bar() const {
    blah = 5; // no compiler error
  }
}
```

note: in this case I do NOT want to get rid of the const at mutable_bar since logical const will be preserved.

Same question, but different perspective: Can I somehow apply the mutable keyword to a method instead of a variable?

Comment: I think you can do `const_cast<Foo*>(this)->blah = 5;`. is that what you need?

Comment: @Elazar: this is UB if the object was actually declared `const` in the first place. *Don't do this!*

Comment: @syam What is declared `const` here, exactly?

Comment: If you have a const object and use const_cast to modify it, you get UB. If you have a reference-to-const that refers to a non-const object, using const_cast and modifying it is not UB.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: `const Foo foo; foo.mutable_bar();`  is UB if `mutable_bar` uses `const_cast` like Elazar said.

Comment: @Elazar, you're the man! but I don't know why you answered in a comment :( syam: what do you mean by UB?

Comment: @syam: I see. you are right. The compiler/loader might even put the object on a read-only memory, or optimize things away, or things like that.

Comment: @Brian: UB is Undefined Behaviour. In other words this is the C++ equivalent of *there be dragons* ie. anything could happen, from appearing to work up to formatting your hard drive or exploding the moon.

Comment: @Brian you see now why did I answer in a comment... ;)
I wasn't sure, and was indeed horribly wrong.

Comment: @Elazar: indeed, who'd want to bear the responsibility of exploding the moon? j/k :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible, at least in C++. You need either `mutable` or non `const` function.
Also there is `const_cast` don't use it to modify things. In case if you modify `const_cast`ed `const` value you get Undefined Behaviour.

## 5.2.11 Const cast

> 7 [ Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer
>   to data member resulting from a const_cast that casts away a const-qualifier73 **may produce undefined
>   behavior** (7.1.6.1). —end note ]

## 7.1.6.1 The cv-qualifiers

> 4 Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.
>   ....
>   5 For another example

```
struct X {
mutable int i;
int j;
};
struct Y {
X x;
Y();
};
const Y y;
y.x.i++; // well-formed: mutable member can be modified
y.x.j++; // ill-formed: const-qualified member modified
Y* p = const_cast<Y*>(&y); // cast away const-ness of y
p->x.i = 99; // well-formed: mutable member can be modified
p->x.j = 99; // undefined: modifies a const member
—end example ]
```

Comment: What exactly does "**may** produce undefined behavior" mean?

Comment: Thanks for that quote. Now, in what way does this depend "on the type of the object"? If the object is const, it's UB, if it's not, it's not. Sorry, but you need to read the rest, too.

Comment: @PaulManta It means that things *may* go wrong, and may not. I'd prefer not to make bets when writing my code.

Comment: @doomster There is no clarification given on when exactly UB may happen. Just noted that it may be so.

Comment: I honestly don't believe that the standard does not specify when this causes UB. Have you checked the referenced 7.1.6.1? I don't have a copy here, but from what a quick search turned up, that's the relevant one.

Comment: @alexrider But isn't that exactly what UB means? The "may" is superfluous.

Comment: @PaulManta According to 7.1.6.1 I've posted it is ok to modify `mutable` values after `const_cast` thus it looks like reference to 7.1.6.1 that clarifies when it is UB and when isn't.

Comment: Maybe you mean the right thing, but nothing here confirms your initial claim "In case if you modify const_casted value you get Undefined Behaviour." The important part in the standard is "any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior", leaving aside exceptions due to `mutable`. Whether you use `const_cast` or some other means for that is irrelevant. Also, using `const_cast` in and of itself does not imply UB, only if you use the result to modify a *const* object. Using the result of `const_cast` to modify a non-const object does not cause UB.

Comment: @doomster Yep that probably wasn't clear enough, `mutable` and othervise non const are exempted, thru initial question explicitly specified that variable expected to be not mutable. Added not on that. And of course usage of `const_cast` doesn't necessary mean UB. But for this particular question it will since there was attempt to modify 'const' value.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to bypass the `const` in this case, by for example:

```
void mutable_bar() const {
    int& p_blah = const_cast<int&>(blah);

    p_blah = 5; // no compiler error
}
```

Or some similar construct. But you are really jumping through hoops to do something that you shouldn't be able to do. And as a comment on another post says, this is "undefined behavior", which means that in some cases it may not even work (or do what you expect it to do).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `const_cast` to make the member not-const in selected cases. This, along with an according comment, might even be a relatively clean solution. At least it's explicit that you break the const in a restricted scope, instead of making it world-wide mutable.

Comment: modifying const_cast'ed value is UB

Comment: Thank you for repeating that it isn't necessarily UB, syam. I don't fully agree to the "Don't do this!" though, I still believe that software developers can make an informed decision.

Comment: @doomster: Sorry I deleted my comment when I saw alexrider's. ;) However as far as **I** am concerned I stand by my "*don't do this*" because UB is so dangerous. YMMV of course. :)

Comment: No harm done, this is just a friendly discussion. And no doubt about it, the general advise not to use const_cast (or any cast at all) is completely right! :)

Comment: Actually as an afterthought, WRT "*developers can make an informed decision*" => one should (ideally) always assume code reuse will happen in the future, so even if you *think* you control everything right now, in a few months/years/decades it won't be true any more. So, if there is even the slightest chance of UB then your code is wrong, full stop. (again, that's just *my* opinion... ;)) I know, I'm nitpicking, I just can't help it... (isn't it the very definition of our job after all, to nitpick on everything?) :-p